# Bitbucket configuration with jenkins

Tags: selenium, jenkins, automation, continuous-integration, bitbucket

Am struck with configuring jenkins and bitbucket , i was able to see few solutions which says "Trigger the build when you commit the changes" but my requirement is completely different, please find below :

1. Jenkins job runs at 9 : 00 am daily in the morning , am using bat file to trigger the job (configured XML in the bat file)
2. Need to access the code from bitbucket daily 9:00 am in the morning.So that when the job triggers , it always takes the latest code from bit bucket repository

Can anyone help me out !! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused - did you install the GIT SCM plugin?

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Git+Plugin

It should allow you to clone a git repository to the workspace - just configure your job with SCM management and select GIT.

Good luck!

Comment: I installed Git , but after entering the URL into the repository URL , displaying an error message "Failed to connect to repository : Could not init C:\Windows\TEMP\hudson1601856142541805873tmp" , could you please help me out with this ?

Comment: One more question , do you think i need to install GIT ? because since am trying to fetch the code from Bit Bucket , do you think it is needed to install GIT ?

Comment: Huh, actually installed the Git and gave the executable path of Git into the field in Global tool configuration , now the error is gone!! Thanks for support  and having a last doubt , where exactly the code from Bit bucket will clone into ?

Comment: This is the error displayed after the build is triggered Caused by: hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "C:\Users\rahul.bommanaboina\AppData\Local\Programs\Git\bin\git.exe -c core.askpass=true fetch --tags --progress https://bitbucket.org/XYZ/testingjenkins.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*" returned status code -1:
stdout: 
stderr:

Comment: Can you please help me out with this ?

Comment: Hi sorry, saw it just now. There might be several reasons and I need the stack-trace to better understand it. did you configure credentials? you're using http\s or SSH?

Comment: Yes i configured credentials under the Repository URL which are of Bit Bucket login and where can i find Stack trace to provide it to you ? am very new to this Bit bucket (sorry for asking basic questions)

Comment: is this something related to "Refspec"  , causing the problem ? , i left the field empty as of now.